# How to load mruby code from external file in C program?

Tags: c, mruby

I'm getting started with [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby). I'm also pretty new to programming in C, so I may not be familiar with many of the basics. I was able to [compile the example mruby program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329146/how-to-compile-an-mruby-example) which loads the ruby code from a string. Now I would like to load it from an external file. Here's the example code that I'm using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mruby.h>

static mrb_value my_c_method(mrb_state *mrb, mrb_value value)
{
  puts("Called my C method");
  return value;
}

int main(void)
{
  mrb_state *mrb = mrb_open();

  struct RClass *mymodule = mrb_define_module(mrb, "MyModule");
  mrb_define_class_method(mrb, mymodule, "my_c_method", my_c_method, MRB_ARGS_NONE());

  mrb_load_string(mrb, "MyModule.my_c_method"); // move this to an external file
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see in the example above, I would like to move the ruby code to an external file. I'm a little confused as to whether or not I can simply "include" the ruby file, or if I need to precompile it into an `.mrb` file. Even then I'm not sure how to include that `.mrb` file when compiling.

What do I need to change to be able to load the ruby code from an external file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `mruby/compile.h` there is a method called `mrb_load_file` which allows you to load a ruby file and execute it with mruby:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <mruby.h>
#include <mruby/compile.h>

static mrb_value my_c_method(mrb_state *mrb, mrb_value value)
{
  puts("Called my C method");
  return value;
}

int main(void)
{
  mrb_state *mrb = mrb_open();

  struct RClass *mymodule = mrb_define_module(mrb, "MyModule");
  mrb_define_class_method(mrb, mymodule, "my_c_method", my_c_method, MRB_ARGS_NONE());

  FILE *f = fopen("example.rb", "r");
  mrb_load_file(mrb, f);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example. If I have a method which takes some parameter (in my ruby file) Ex: ef helloworld(var1, var2), how do I load the file and call this method from C?

Comment: Also do you know how to extract information from mrb_value structure? For example, how to read a string, integer, double etc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is stored in file `foo`, all you need is to open the file and read it. To open the file, you need `fopen()`, defined in stdio.h. You can then read it line by line using `fgets()`. I'm not familiar with mruby, so I'm not exactly sure if mrb_load_string expects that every mruby code is in a single line. I will assume so. Here's how you can do it:

```
#define MAX_CODE_SIZE 128
FILE *code;
char code_buf[128]
code = fopen("foo", "r");
if (code == NULL) {
    /* File couldn't be opened, handle error case... */
}
fgets(code_buf, MAX_CODE_SIZE, code);
/* Do some work ... */

fclose(code); /* Don't forget to close the file */
```

This piece of code reads the first line of file `foo`, up to a limit of 127 characters (including newline), and stores it in `code_buf`. You can then call `mrb_load_string`:

```
mrb_load_string(mrb, code);
```

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, I never touched mruby, but from what I saw, `mrb_load_string` expects a `char *` with the code, and you want that to come from a file. That's how you do it.

If you want to read a file with code in multiple lines, you have no choice but to allocate a large enough buffer and read it using `fread()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 128
#define MAX_LINES 256
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE MAX_LINE_LENGTH*MAX_LINES

char code[MAX_FILE_SIZE];

int read_code(char *filepath) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 0;
    fread(code, 1, MAX_FILE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

This function reads the whole file (assuming it doesn't exceed our buffer limits). `code` is global because you can easily reach the stack capacity if you allocate large local variables (another alternative is to use dynamic allocation). When you call `read_code()`, you should make sure to check its return value, to check for possible errors upon opening the file. Also, you can play with `fread()`'s return value to know if the buffer size wasn't enough to read everything.

Just make sure you don't forget to close the file when you're done.

**EDIT:** For the `fgets()` version, please note that in case the line holds less than 128 characters, newline will be retained in `code_buf`. You may want to set `code_buf[strlen(code_buf)-1]` to `'\0'` if that's the case.

**UPDATE:**

From our discussion on the comments below, I am updating my answer with a rudimentary parser to enable you to read the ruby file at compile time. Basically, the parser will read your ruby file and generate an output file with valid C code that inserts the file's content in a char array. Special characters are accordingly escaped. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inline insert(int, FILE *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *out, *in;
    int c;
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <input_file> <output_file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    out = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    if (out == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to create or write to %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (in == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to read %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    fputs("#ifndef MRUBY_CODE_FILE_GUARD\n", out);
    fputs("#define MRUBY_CODE_FILE_GUARD\n", out);
    fputs("char mruby_code[] = \"", out);
    while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF)
        insert(c, out);
    fputs("\";\n", out);
    fputs("#endif\n", out);
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

void inline insert(int c, FILE *fp) {
    switch (c) {
        case '\a':
            fputs("\\a", fp);
            break;
        case '\b':
            fputs("\\b", fp);
            break;
        case '\f':
            fputs("\\f", fp);
            break;
        case '\n':
            fputs("\\n", fp);
            break;
        case '\r':
            fputs("\\r", fp);
            break;
        case '\t':
            fputs("\\t", fp);
            break;
        case '\v':
            fputs("\\v", fp);
            break;
        case '\\':
            fputs("\\\\", fp);
            break;
        case '\'':
            fputs("\\'", fp);
            break;
        case '"':
            fputs("\\\"", fp);
            break;
        default:
            fputc(c, fp);
    }
}
```

Now, go back to your original program and add the following include directive in the beginning:

```
#include mruby_code.h
```

You have to do the following steps to compile a runnable program, assuming that this parser was compiled into a file named `fileparser.c`:

- Run `./fileparser /path/to/mruby_code_file /path/to/program/mruby_code.h`.
- Compile your original program (it will include `mruby_code.h`)

The mruby code is provided in a variable called `mruby_code`. This is a char array, so you can pass it to `mrb_load_string`. And voila, you got the mruby file read **once** at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely a start and helpful to know. I came across an Objective-C example that made use of `mrb_read_irep_file`. I'm wondering if mruby has a method that simplifies this answer a little bit. I'm not sure how to navigate the mruby source code to find methods like this that may help.

Comment: Well, as I said, I never looked at mruby, so I can't help you any further. This is the pure C way to do it. Maybe someone with further ruby knowledge will answer this question.

Comment: One more question: does your example read the file at runtime? Is there a way to include the file at compile time to, sort of, package it up?

Comment: It reads the file at runtime. If you're not comfortable with the overhead of doing that every time you run the program, the only alternative I can see is to code a C program that opens an mruby code file, generates a C file with proper code that shoves the file's content in a char *, and then include that file when calling the compiler. That would be really cool, I might try to code such a program just for fun. If I do it, I'll update my answer. Apart from that, every other possible approach (even mruby library functions) will most likely read the file in run time.

Comment: Actually, it would be really cool, because you wouldn't have to worry about buffer size. I'm going to code this up, that was a very nice idea! The only catch is that if you change your ruby code, you have to recompile your C program.

Comment: @Andrew updated my answer with my implementation to the approach I described. Hope it works for you, I tested it here and it worked like a charm.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I learned quite a bit from that example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using mrb_load_file:

```
FILE *f = fopen("the_file.rb", "r");
mrb_load_file(mrb, f);
fclose(f) ;
```

The manual option is to read the filename:

```
int load_ruby_file_to_state(char *filename, mrb_state *state) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r") ;
    if (!file) return -1 ;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long length = ftell(file) ;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *code = malloc(length + 1) ;

    if (code) {
        fread(code, 1, length, file) ;
        code[length + 1] = '\0' ;
    } else {
        return -1 ;
    }

    fclose(file) ;

    mrb_load_string(state, code) ;
    free(code) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

And load file: `load_ruby_file_to_state("the_file.rb", mrb) ;`

Do note that `mrb_load_file()` will give a segfault if the file doesn't exist, so it's better to check for the file existence or if it's readable.